# How to scrape additional pages of the main page in a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am fairly new to python. With some help, i wrote some code to scrape some data off a web-page. However, i am only able to scrape the first page of each link based on the code.

Currently, the code below allows me to scrape the links of each year's data (https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=1949) based on the first page.

however, for some of the years, there are additional pages (eg page 2, page 3, page 4) in the specific years' link (https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=1949&lang=&page=2)
(https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=1949&lang=&page=3)

i was wondering if it was possible to retrieve the additional links based on the additional pages for each year's data.

```
#get the additional links within each Year Link
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36'}
main_url = "https://aviation-safety.net/database/"

def get_and_parse_url(main_url):
    result = requests.get(main_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'html.parser')
    data_table = [main_url + i['href'] for i in soup.select('[href*=Year]')]
    return data_table

with requests.Session() as s:
    data_table = get_and_parse_url(main_url)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data_table, columns=['url'])
    datatable2 = [] #create outside so can append to it

    for anker in df.url:
        result = s.get(anker, headers = headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'html.parser')
        datatable2.append(['https://aviation-safety.net' + i['href'] for i in soup.select('[href*="database/record"]')])

 #flatten list of lists
datatable2 = [i for sublist in datatable2 for i in sublist]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(datatable2 , columns=['add_url'])
for i in df2.add_url: 
    print(i)
```

Any form of help is much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could determine the number of additional pages there are, for each initial records page,  by gathering matches for child `a` tags within element with class `pagenumbers` (limited to top one by adding nth-of-type); do this in a list comprehension that generates the actual additional page urls; then using an additional loop gather for those pages. At time of writing this yields 22,629 distinct links.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

base = 'https://aviation-safety.net/database/'
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
inner_links = []

def get_soup(url):
    r = s.get(url, headers = headers)
    soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')
    return soup 

with requests.Session() as s:
    soup = get_soup('https://aviation-safety.net/database/')
    initial_links = [base + i['href'] for i in soup.select('[href*="Year="]')]

    for link in initial_links:
        soup = get_soup(link)
        inner_links+= ['https://aviation-safety.net' + i['href'] for i in soup.select('[href*="database/record"]')]
        pages = [f'{link}&lang=&page={i.text}' for i in soup.select('.pagenumbers:nth-of-type(2) a')]

        for page in pages:
            soup = get_soup(page)
            inner_links+= ['https://aviation-safety.net' + i['href'] for i in soup.select('[href*="database/record"]')]
```

Comment: Many thanks QHarr! The code works and your explanation was really informative.